# QListWidgetに表示されている文字の情報を取得してJSONファイルを作成したい

Tags: python, python3, json, csv

Python初学者です。
CSVファイルから情報を取得して、QListWidgetに表示させました。
そのQListWidgetから情報を取得して、Jsonファイルを作成するコードを書きました。
しかし、ファイルは作成したのですが、最後の１行しか入ってません。
QListWidgetを使うことが間違っているのでしょうか？

**環境：**
Windows 10
Python3
PySide2

コードは以下のように書きました。

```
def callback_create_file_button_clicked(self):
    for row in range(self.listwgt.count()):
        item = self.listwgt.item(row)
        jsonlist = item.text()
    filename = "C:/Users/User/Documents/Jymaker/json/sample.json"
    with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf_8") as f:
        json.dump(jsonlist, f)
```

csvファイルを読み込む部分です。

```
def load_csv(self, file):
    json_list =[]
    with open(file, "r", encoding="utf_8") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            json_list.append(",".join(row))

    return(json_list)
```

返り値を受け取る部分です。

```
def callback_file_dialog_button_clicked(self):
    file, filter_ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
        self, "Open CSV", "C:/Users/User/Documents/Jymaker/csv", "CSV (*.csv)"
    )

    if file:
        self.line_edit.setText(file)
        json_list = self.load_csv(file)
        self.listwgt.clear()
        self.listwgt.addItems(json_list)
```

Comment: for loop の最後で `jsonlist = item.text()` としてしまっているので一行処理する度に上書きしてしまっていますね。。。

Comment: これがないとitermから文字情報を取り出せないのです。
.text()メソッドを調べています。

Comment: 本来は `jsonlist += item.text()` とするのではないでしょうか

Comment: jsdata.append(item.text())と記述して解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決した場合にはコメント欄ではなく、ぜひ個別の回答として投稿してみてください。